# Is there a way to assign values to a multidimensional array in Fortran without using nested loops?

Tags: arrays, loops, multidimensional-array, fortran, fortran95

I am trying to assign 216 values from an array to a 6x6x6 matrix in Fortran. This is my code:

```
    y =  0
    do x = 1,6
    do z = 13,18
            do x1 = 19,24
                y = y+1
                omega_plus(x,z,x1) = omegap_sec(y)
            end do
       end do
    end do
```

`omegap_sec` is a 1d arrays having 216 values.

Is there a way to write something like this:
`omega_plus[1:6,13:18,19:24] = omegap_sec[1:216]` in Fortran?

Comment: As with the linked question, you can `reshape` the rank-1 array to the rank-3 array. You'll need to reorder the elements though, so that `omega_plus` varies most rapidly in the final dimension.